# Why is the sizeof of a structure larger than the sum of its parts?

Tags: c

```
       typedef struct{
       short age;
       int money;
       char c; 
       }Persoana;   

       int main(void){
       Persoana *a = malloc(sizeof(Persoana));
       printf("%ld   %ld",sizeof(a->money),sizeof(a->age));
       printf("   %ld\n",sizeof(*a));   } ~
```

The code prints "4212".4 and 2 are ok but how so 12???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is non-constructive, as it has to do with the basics.

Comment: `sizeof()` needs `%zu`.

Comment: @gsamaras just being basic does not make a question off-topic.

Comment: Oh that was from the auto-generated message, of course @Philipp! But still questions of this kind pollute SO IMHO.

Comment: @Philipp on general yeah, basic doesn't mean off-topic i agree but  in this specific case , there's no problem and the OP made no effort, i am voting to close it also.

Comment: The output does not suite the code. Please be more accurate. Accurate questions lead to accurate answers.

Comment: @haris: Your edit is based on an assumption. I'd tend to roll this back. It's the OP's task to provide meaningful and accurate info.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry,wont happen next time :)

Comment: Why not just clean up the mess now?

Comment: And just to state this explicitly again: Questions *about* basics are very welcome at SO, as all well crafted questions are. SO isn't a closed, nerdish club.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's to demonstrate padding issues done by the compiler. What it (the compiler) did here was to align each part of the struct to 4 byte word boundaries (=> 4*3 = 12 bytes) instead of packing them into 9 bytes. This is performed by the compiler to allow for data member access that respects the target CPU memory access patterns.